# PHP Why does array_walk not work with DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName

Tags: php, domdocument, array-walk

just wondering why the following code **doesn't** itterate through
DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML('<html><head>...blablabla...</html>');
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
array_walk($elements, 'var_dump'); // doesn't work ?>
```

But the following code **does** work:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML('<html><head>...blablabla...</html>');
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($elements as $element) {
  var_dump($element); // does work
} ?>
```

Comment: The return value from `getElementsByTagName()` is a `DOMNodeList` __object__, not an `array`; it's `Traversable`, so `foreach` will work, but `array_walk()` requires an actual array argument

Comment: @MarkBaker that's the answer ...

Comment: @MarkBaker it's funny that `array_walk` doesn't generate an error when called with a non-array, no?

Comment: From the PHP docs: `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.`, but it will also give a warning if you have error logging enabled - [Demo](https://3v4l.org/lguWH)

Comment: @MarkBaker can u add this as the answer. I would like to accept that as an answer. Allthough i expected PHP to generate an error, but it doest. (maybe should have read the php manual better for array_walk) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value from `getElementsByTagName()` is a `DOMNodeList` **object**, not an array: a `DOMNodeList` object is `Traversable`, so a `foreach()` will iterate over it; but `array_walk()` requires an *actual* array argument, so it can't be used with `array_walk()`.

Calling `array_walk()` with an argument that isn't an array won't generate an Error, but it will generate a Warning, and it will return a result of boolean `false`.

Comment: Thanks, as Paul Crovella did say array_walk **can** iterate over object properties, thats why i tried array_walk.

Comment: Interesting observation @PaulCrovella, that's a new one on me.... interesting to see that it's still in PHP7, but not in HHVM